# Does Q3ListView fail to unregister from Qt backing store or the code is wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qt4.8

I have the following use case (doesn't really make sense, because it's minimized from a real-life working example, however I think it's still technically correct):

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
  Dialog(QWidget* parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    {
      new Q3ListView(this); // this will crash
//    new QWidget(this);    // this won't crash
    }
};
```

Depending on what is added to the `Dialog` the program will crash or not when deleting the `Dialog` instance (as indicated by the comments in the snippet), but only when main window's flags have been modified. Here is the code for the `MainWindow` class, which uses `Dialog`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
  // the fact that the widget (dialog) below 
  // has no chance to show seems irrelevant. 
  // In the real scenario I have, the widget is shown on 
  // the screen and is closed by the user. 
  // I've just put the whole sequence of pieces of code 
  // that result from signal/slot calls, that in turn 
  // result from a point&click scenario in our application 
  // into the following function for brevity.
  void go()
    {        
      auto dialog = new Dialog(this);
      dialog->show();
      dialog->close();
      
      disableAlwaysOnTop();

      delete dialog; // or dialog->deleteLater();
    }

  void disableAlwaysOnTop()
    {
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_Resized, true);

      Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
      setWindowFlags(flags ^ (Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint));

      setVisible(true);
    }
};
```

and the implementation of `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow mainWindow;
  mainWindow.show();
  mainWindow.go();
  return app.exec();
}
```

All lines seem essential to reproduce the crash.

Is it a bug in Qt, or am I doing something wrong?

Manually deleting widget's children is allowed, and they should automatically unregister from their parents as indicated in the quote from the manual below. In my real-life case the widget is deleted to disappear from the GUI, and it works in case of other widget combinations. As indicated in the comment above, changing `delete dialog;` to `dialog->deleteLater();` doesn't help.

It seems that there is a problem in removing the `Q3ListView` instance from Qt's backing store, here is the stack trace:

> QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetBackingStore::staticContents(QWidget * parent, const QRect & withinClipRect) Line 499    C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetBackingStore::sync() Line 1200   C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::syncBackingStore() Line 1896    C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QWidget::event(QEvent * event) Line 8694    C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QMainWindow::event(QEvent * event) Line 1479    C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e) Line 4565    C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e) Line 4530  C++
>
> QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) Line 955  C++
>
> QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) Line 231   C++
>
> QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver, int event_type, QThreadData * data) Line 1579    C++
>
> QtCored4.dll!qt_internal_proc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wp, __int64 lp) Line 498    C++
>
> [External Code]
>
> QtCored4.dll!QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags flags) Line 823    C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QGuiEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags flags) Line 1216 C++
>
> QtCored4.dll!QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags flags) Line 150   C++
>
> QtCored4.dll!QEventLoop::exec(QFlags flags) Line 204    C++
>
> QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::exec() Line 1227 C++
>
> QtGuid4.dll!QApplication::exec() Line 3824  C++
>
> qt_bug.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 60    C++

And the piece of Qt's code that attempts to use a pointer to a deleted object in the line indicated in the stack trace:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    QWidget *w = staticWidgets.at(i);
    QWidgetPrivate *wd = w->d_func();
    if (!wd->isOpaque || !wd->extra || wd->extra->staticContentsSize.isEmpty()  // ****
        || !w->isVisible() || (parent && !parent->isAncestorOf(w))) {
        continue;
    }
```

(`wd` points to a deleted object at the line marked with the comment).

*Disclaimer:*
I know that more elegant solutions exist but this is legacy code, and according to [Qt's manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html):

> You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents.

this code is valid.

We've reproduced the problem on Windows 7 (MSVC 2010 SP1, CL 16), Windows 8 (MSVC 2013 U4, CL 18) and Fedora 20 (GCC 4.8.3).

Comment: Looks like a genuine Qt bug. It's a corner case: it seems you should not delete instantiated and shown widgets before the event loop had a chance to run. I don't think it's specific to `Q3ListView`. My bet is that if you change `delete dialog` to `dialog->deleteLater()`, it won't crash. Perhaps if you insert `qApp->processEvents()` before the `delete` it won't crash either. Please let us know what platform it's on, as it's important too. I might try to reproduce it.

Comment: TL;DR: Your code is not wrong, but I doubt that there's much tests in Qt code base to make sure that shown, displayed widgets can be deleted before the event loop has drained. I bet such shenanigans could crash in Qt 5 as well.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for your input. I forgot to mention that I've tried `dialog->deleteLater()` and unfortunately it doesn't help. We've reproduced the crash on Windows 7, Windows 8 and Arch Linux. I'll update the question.

Comment: It would be great if you (or someone else) would manage to reproduce the issue, so I'll be sure it's not something in our environment (however, 3 different machines and OSes reduce the possibility :) ), and perhaps post a bug report.

Comment: @KubaOber Also, I forgot to mention - the fact that the widget has no chance to show seems irrelevant. In the real scenario I have, the widget is shown on the screen and is closed by the user. I've just put the whole sequence of pieces of code that result from signal/slot calls, that in turn result from point&click scenario in our application into one function (`go`) for brevity.

Comment: Does it happen in Qt 5 too?

Comment: @KubaOber Didn't have the chance to check as I don't have Qt5 compiled right now, but IIRC Qt5 doesn't have Qt3 support part so you can't use the `Q3ListView` widget.

Comment: I don't think that `Q3ListView` is special in any respect. It should be possible to minimize it not to be needed. I'll take a look at it this weekend.

Comment: @KubaOber I think that `Q3ScrollView` is special, which is inherited by `Q3ListView`. When you change it to `Q3Table` which also derives from `Q3ScrollView` it also crashes. But, as you can see in the example, ordinary `QWidget` (I've tried also `QLabel` and `QButton` and `QTreeWidget`) won't crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've filed a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47231). Since it concerns an old version of the library no hopes that it will be fixed.

We are successively removing Qt3Support anyway and so is everyone advised ;)